# Decorator with parameters

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators

Can you explain me how the following decorator works:

```
def set_ev_cls(ev_cls, dispatchers=None):
    def _set_ev_cls_dec(handler):
        if 'callers' not in dir(handler):
            handler.callers = {}
        for e in _listify(ev_cls):
            handler.callers[e] = _Caller(_listify(dispatchers), e.__module__)
        return handler
    return _set_ev_cls_dec


@set_ev_cls(ofp_event.EventOFPSwitchFeatures, CONFIG_DISPATCHER)
def _switch_features_handler(self, ev):
    datapath = ev.msg.datapath
    ....
```

Please, don't go into details on what's going on inside the function. I'm interested in how the decorator with parameters wrap methods here. By the way, it's a code snippet from Ryu (event registration mechanism).

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, a decorator is just a function that gets called with a function. In particular, the following are (almost) the same thing:

```
@spam
def eggs(arg): pass

def eggs(arg): pass
eggs = spam(eggs)
```

So, what happens when the decorator takes parameters? Same thing:

```
@spam(arg2)
def eggs(arg): pass

def eggs(arg): pass
eggs = spam(arg2)(eggs)
```

Now, notice that the function `_set_ev_cls_dec`, which is ultimately returned and used in place of `_switch_features_handler`, is a local function, defined inside the decorator. That means it can be a closure over variables from the outer function—including the parameters of the outer function. So, it can use the `handler` argument at call time, plus the `ev_cls` and `dispatchers` arguments that it got at decoration time.

So:

- `set_ev_cls_dev` creates a local function and returns a closure around its `ev_cls` and `dispatchers` arguments, and returns that function.
- That closure gets called with `_switch_features_handler` as its parameter, and it modifies and returns that parameter by adding a `callers` attribute, which is a dict of `_Caller` objects built from  that closed-over `dispatchers` parameter and keyed off that closed-over `ev_cls` parameter.

Answer (score 3):

Explain how it works without detailing what's going on inside? That kind of sounds like "explain without explaining," but here's a rough walkthrough:

1. Think of `set_ev_cls` as a factory for decorators. It's there to catch the arguments at the time the decorator is invoked:

   ```
   @set_ev_cls(ofp_event.EventOFPSwitchFeatures, CONFIG_DISPATCHER)
   ```

   And return a function, `_set_ev_cls_dec` that has its variables bound to:

   ```
   ev_cls = ofp_event.EventOFPSwitchFeatures
   dispatchers = CONFIG_DISPATCHER
   ```

   Or put another way, you now have a 'customized' or 'parametrized' dispatcher that's logically equivalent to:

   ```
   def custom_decorator(handler):
       if 'callers' not in dir(handler):
           handler.callers = {}
       for e in _listify(ofp_event.EventOFPSwitchFeatures):
           handler.callers[e] = _Caller(_listify(CONFIG_DISPATCHER), e.__module__)
       return handler
   ```

   (If you captured the values of `ofp_event.EventOFPSwitchFeatures` and `CONFIG_DISPATCHER` at the moment the `@set_ev_cls(...)` was called).
2. The `custom_decorator` of step 1 is applied to `_switch_features_handler`as a more traditional unparameterized decorator.

Comment: I selected 'abarnert' because he was the first one to reply and both his and your replies are amazing!

Comment: The "factory for decorators" and "'parameterized' dispatcher" terminology are both great ways to put it.