# How to use decorators in Python

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators

I recently started learning about Decorators in Python and found the following piece of code which got me confused.

```
HANDLERS = {}

def handler_for(template):
    def decorator(f):
        HANDLERS[template] = f
        return f
    return decorator

def get_template(template, **kwargs):
    #This function got me all confused. How does HANDLERS.get(template, None) works and how does it return demo_func() function?
    return HANDLERS.get(template, None)

def email(template, **kwargs):
    handler = get_template(template, **kwargs)
    contents = handler(**kwargs)
    print contents

@handler_for('demo')
def demo_func(**kwargs):
    #Do something and return the String

if __name__ == "__main__":
    email('demo')
```

I tried debugging with Python Debugger but I'm still getting confused as how the get_template() function calls the decorator which returns the function name.

Comment: Does [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26981310/decorator-with-parameters/26981383#26981383) explain everything you're looking for, or not?

Comment: @abarnert: Looking into it.

Comment: OK, I think my explanation there was better (plus, there's another good explanation by someone else), even if it's not as directly related to your question, so if it's enough to solve your problem, it's probably better to close this as a duplicate. But if not, see my answer here.

Answer (score 0):

> I tried debugging with Python Debugger but I'm still getting confused as how the get_template() function calls the decorator which returns the function name.

Well… it doesn't. The decorator gets called by you using `@handler_for('demo')`.

Decorators aren't as complicated as they seem, once you keep in mind that the following are equivalent:

```
@beans
def spam(eggs):
    print(eggs)

def spam(eggs):
    print(eggs)
spam = beans(spam)
```

That `beans` doesn't have to be just an identifier, it can be (almost) any expression, even a function call. So, your code is doing this:

```
demo_func = handler_for('demo')(demo_func)
```

`handler_for` takes `'demo'` as the value of its `template` parameter. It then defines and returns a local function, `decorator`. So, when it's called, it has access to its own argument, `f`, and also to the closed-over `template` value from when it was constructed. That function is immediately called with `demo_func` as its `f` value, and it just stashes the function in the `HANDLERS` dictionary and returns it unchanged. So, inlining everything:

```
def demo_func(**kwargs):
    #Do something and return the String
template = 'demo'
HANDLERS[template] = demo_func
demo_func = demo_func
```

So, because `get_template` just looks things up in `HANDLERS`, when you later call `get_template('demo')` it will find `demo_func`.